# How to place tkinter entries into a method?

Tags: python, input, tkinter

Basically, the problem is that this doesn't work:

```
def run():
    print song.get()

def startGUI():
    root = Tk()
    songLabel = Label(root, text="Enter the song:")
    song = Entry(root)
    submit = Button(root, text="Download", command = run)

    songLabel.pack()
    song.pack()
    submit.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    startGUI()
```

Whereas this does:

```
def run():
    print song.get()

root = Tk()
songLabel = Label(root, text="Enter the song:")
song = Entry(root)
submit = Button(root, text="Download", command = run)

songLabel.pack()
song.pack()
submit.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Why is it that I can't place an entry into a method without getting errors?
The specific error here is that 'song' isn't being found in the run method, giving the following error:

*NameError: global name 'song' is not defined*

How do I change it so that this error doesn't happen, but the entry is still in a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`song` in the first code is local variable, which is only accessible inside `startGUI` function, not accessible in `run`.

`song` in the second code is global variable which can be access anywhere in the module.

Following code shows one way to make first code to work. (pass song to run explicityly).

```
from Tkinter import *

def run(song):
    print song.get()

def startGUI():
    root = Tk()
    songLabel = Label(root, text="Enter the song:")
    song = Entry(root)
    submit = Button(root, text="Download", command=lambda: run(song))

    songLabel.pack()
    song.pack()
    submit.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    startGUI()
```

Another way (put run inside startGUI):

```
from Tkinter import *

def startGUI():
    def run():
        print song.get()
    root = Tk()
    songLabel = Label(root, text="Enter the song:")
    song = Entry(root)
    submit = Button(root, text="Download", command=run)

    songLabel.pack()
    song.pack()
    submit.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    startGUI()
```

You can also use class.

```
from Tkinter import *

class SongDownloader:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        songLabel = Label(root, text="Enter the song:")
        self.song = Entry(root)
        submit = Button(root, text="Download", command=self.run)
        songLabel.pack()
        self.song.pack()
        submit.pack()

    def run(self):
        print self.song.get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    SongDownloader(root)
    root.mainloop()
```